# I want the background to be visible over the Div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a page in which i have used an image as a background for it. and inside the body i have created div elements with background color. but my div element is overlapping over the body background image. I want my **body background image** to be visible over the **div elements**. 
I have seen in some of  the sites that background is visible over the other elements.

My html code is as follows:

```
<body>

<div class="travel-section">
    <div class="travel-inner-section">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
/*background-color:rgba(0,57,77,1);*/
background-image:url("../images/travel.jpg");
}

.travel-section{
margin-right:4px;
margin-left:4px;
margin-top:120px;
height:240px;
background-color:#2ecc71;

 }

 .travel-inner-section{
margin-right:4px;
margin-left:4px;
height:40px;
background-color:#27ae60;
opacity:0.5;
box-shadow:2px green;
 }
```

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand...

Comment: I don't get it, you want to hide the other elements behind the background, if so why not just hide them outright with display none ?

Comment: if you want the background of the `.travel-section` to be transparent, just do `background-color: transparent;`. If you want it semi-transparent, use a color with an alpha channel like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` (50% black)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but if I got the idea, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barbu110/dcASD/1/) is an example.

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://hdlatestwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Green-Bubbles-Awesome-Background.jpg);
}
.travel-section {
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:120px;
    height:240px;
    background-color: rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.7);
}
```

When you set the `background-color` property to `rgba()`, you have to set its RGB values, and the Alpha value. This will help you to only have a **translucent background**<sup>1</sup>. If you want a **translucent div**<sup>2</sup>, then just set the `opacity` property to a value between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%).

<sup>1</sup> Having a translucent background means that only the background of you div will have the opacity between 0 and 0.99, because the contents of the div will be opaque (alpha = 1).

<sup>2</sup> Setting the `opacity` to a value between 0 and 0.99 will lead to a translucent element. This means that both the background and the contents of the div will be translucent.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this ?
Where you can't see the background of the div, but the background of the element behind it is visible?

You will need to add background: transparent to your css.

So like this:

```
.travel-section{
    margin-right:4px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:120px;
    height:240px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kg8Z8/1/

Or do you want to see the background-color of the div, but see through it a little?
then you would have to use opacity, like this:

```
.travel-section{
    margin-right:4px;
       margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:120px;
    height:240px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kg8Z8/

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BH97G/)

If you want the `div` to be transparent, you can do this:

```
.travel-section{
  margin-right:4px;
  margin-left:4px;
  margin-top:120px;
  height:240px;
  background-color:rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.6);
}
```

`rgba` is `red`, `green,` `blue`, `alpha`. `alpha` is what controls how transparent something is.

If not, you can put `display:none;` in `.travel-section` and it will hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `opacity:0.3` to the travel-section, your body background will be visible in that case.

```
.travel-section{
margin-right:4px;
margin-left:4px;
margin-top:120px;
height:240px;
background-color:#2ecc71;
opacity: 0.3;
 }
```

Adjust the value of opacity between 0 to 1.